# Convert byte* to int in Arduino

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, c++, nodemcu, mqtt

I am trying to convert `byte*` value to `int` here is how I have it.

```
void mqttCallback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {

  String topicStr = topic;
  int* payload_value;
  int updates_cal;

    payload_value = (int*)payload;
    //updates_cal = *payload_value;


    Serial.print((int)payload_value);


  delay(1);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("-----------------------");

}
```

I am getting MQTT payload as Integer value. Which I want to receive in my NodeMCU (ESP8266).

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to convert a `byte *` to `int`, then you already have it, assuming that `int` is large enough to store an address on your platform. But what would be the point of this? Your `payload_value` is an address.

Comment: @AnT I just want integer (without pointer). How can I Serial.print it?

Comment: **What** specific integer do you want? Taken from where?

Comment: @AnT the integer is published by MQTT as a message.

Comment: The description of the format of MQQT message suggest that the second part of my answer (as well as Duncan C's) answer is the proper way to do it.

Comment: I tried that but its throwing error. Here is how the error looks like:

Comment: Exception (9):
epc1=0x40202430 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x3ffeeb79 depc=0x00000000

>>>stack>>>

` ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,6)`

Comment: Considering the lengthy comments in the accepted answer, please consider editing this questions and / or title to reflect a more clear statement of what was desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the comments, you are actually receiving your integer data as text, as a sequence of ASCII characters. This is what you send yourself using `mosquitto_pub`. The buffer is apparently not zero-terminated.

If these characters represent an integer value, then the way to retrieve it as an integer value would be

```
char buffer[128];

// Make sure here that `length` is smaller than the above buffer size. 
// Otherwise, you'd need a bigger buffer

// Form a C-string from the payload
memcpy(buffer, payload, length);
buffer[length] = '\0';

// Convert it to integer
char *end = nullptr;
long value = strtol(buffer, &end, 10);

// Check for conversion errors
if (end == buffer || errno == ERANGE)
  ; // Conversion error occurred
else
  Sterial.println(value);
```

---

Another approach, which avoids using a separate large[ish] buffer just for the purposes of zero-termination, would be

```
// Build a `scanf` format string that will read no more than `length`
// characters without relying on zero-termination of the payload
char format[16];
snprintf(format, sizeof format, "%%%ud", length);

// Convert the payload
int payload_value = 0;
if (sscanf((const char *) payload, format, &payload_value) == 1)
  Serial.println(payload_value);
else
  ; // Conversion error occurred
```

However, this approach is less protected from integer overflow than the previous one.

---

Note that most of the above "jumping through the hoops" is dedicated to adding a zero-terminator to the input buffer. If instead you opt for ensuring zero-termination on the sender's side, then it would all reduce to a simple

```
// Convert C-string to integer
char *end = nullptr;
long value = strtol((const char *) payload, &end, 10);

// Check for conversion errors
if (end == buffer || errno == ERANGE)
  ; // Conversion error occurred
else
  Sterial.println(value);
```

No extra buffers required.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93108/discussion-on-answer-by-ant-convert-byte-to-int-in-arduino).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you found an answer yet, but I had the exact same issue and eventually came up with this:

```
   payload[length] = '\0'; // Add a NULL to the end of the char* to make it a string.
   int aNumber = atoi((char *)payload);
```

Pretty simple in the end!

Comment: Keep in mind that ```payload[length]``` is not part of the memory dedicated to the payload variable. The last item in the memory space of an array always is ```length-1```. Your approach may work most of the time, but you could potentialy overwrite other variables located at that place in memory.

Answer (score 0):

`byte*` means "pointer to byte(s). It is usually used to point to a byte buffer, and usually will also have a length value so you know how many bytes are in the buffer. It looks like your function does have a length value.

If you're certain that the data in the `payload` parameter is a single int, and the length is correct for an int (2 bytes on Arduino I believe) then you should be able to cast the pointer to `int*` type and then fetch the value from the buffer:

```
void mqttCallback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  String topicStr = topic;
  int payload_value;
  int updates_cal;

  if (length >= 2) {
    //Cast payload to an int pointer and fetch the value
    intValue = *((int*)payload); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but there is some error. Its resetting my NodeMCU. Exception number is 9 is througing.